# Using labels with simpower simulink library

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, simpowersystems

I was simulating a winding generator using the simpower library from Matlab's simulink and the schematic turn to be quite big. That when I discovered that labels (blocks "Goto" and "From" in simulink) don't connect to simpower wires. What are the options to solve this?

[image: The blocks simply refuses to connect!]

Answer (score 1):

The SimPowerSystems connections are physical connections, they are not like normal Simulink signals. You cannot have Goto/From blocks for physical connections, it doesn't make sense, plus it would make the model completely unreadable. If you think about it in a physical sense, you cannot break a physical shaft half-way through and say "go and pick the other half at this place".

Comment: I dont agree about the point tough, it is still just a model so is should be permitted. Anyway atleast some simscape connections can be made to work this way, its just very complicated and nasty.

Comment: @joojaa You may agree or not, the point is you can't do it as far as I know.

Comment: My point is you should not argue about the semantics of as wether or not it makes sense, just about the fact that they are not normal connections.

Comment: I was trying to expand my answer beyond the simple "you can't do it, full stop" by explaining the rationale behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I understand your point of view @am304 but I think that Joojaa opinion makes more sense (it's just a model and models are made to make life simpler to explain!) and I hope that in a future update labels are implemented in this library.

Comment: @joojaa As far as I know, you can't do this with Simscape connections either, for the same reasons, but I stand to be corrected if I'm wrong. Henrique, Sorry I haven't got an alternative or work around to offer.